# How to fix a value of an integer rather than throwing an exception?

Tags: java, exception, int, floor

I need to fix the value of user input using floor function rather than having it to throw an exception and stop. Is it possible?
If a user inputs 8.3; it should become 8 and not throw an Exception. Any idea how to perform this?

Part of code that I have written goes as this:

```
try{
    int y=0;
    Scanner inputY = new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.println("Enter an Integer between 1-9");
    y = inputY.nextInt();
    catch(InputMismatchException e){
    return 0;
    }
    finally{
        System.out.println("The input number was not an integer between 1-9");
        System.exit(0);
    }
```

Comment: `Scanner` provides a family of `hasXyz` methods for testing if reading `nextXyz` is going to throw an exception or not. You can use this method to decide if the `Scanner` is looking at an `int` or a `double`, and read whichever one is available.

Answer (score 2):

Don't use `nextInt()` but `nextDouble()` and make a conversion from double to int.

```
double y = inputY.nextDouble();
int x = (int) y;
```